# Image from canvas is not displayed when the div is created dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#AddButton").bind('click', function(event){


    if(document.getElementById('optionselectthree').value=='drawtab')
    {
    divshow();
    clone();
    event.stopPropagation();

    }
    else if(...)
    {

    ..

    }


    });
 });
```

**divshow() function:**

```
function divshow(){

var newImageBoxdiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("class",'demo');

newImageBoxdiv.html('<img id="Imagedisplay" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; width:auto; width:100%; height:100%; cursor:move; position:absolute;" />');

newImageBoxdiv.insertAfter("#imagedemo");
$('.demo').show(); 
}
```

**clone() function:**

```
function clone(){

var c=document.getElementById("can");
var d=c.toDataURL("image/png");

document.getElementById("Imagedisplay").src=d;

}
```

Hi Guys, I am trying to draw an image on canvas and then display the drawn image (clone() function) on div which is called dynamically using divshow() function. Problem is that when i click on #AddButton, it displays the div without the image when the image src is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are setting src before toDataURL is finished. You may need to use a callback to fire once toDataURL is complete, and set src within that. Try logging the value of d right before you set src to check this.

Unfortunately I've encountered this problem myself and don't know of a sure fire way to add a callback to toDataURL; toBlob has one but doesn't seem to be implemented properly yet.

Comment: Yes. See i am getting the image if i try to display it on another div. I just want to know if i don't implement <img> tag inside the divshow() function and declare this somewhere statically. Would i be able to get this img tag between the div which is created dynamically?

Comment: Yeah, that can be done. You can use similar syntax to what you already have. Just call *var imgeElement = $(document.createElement("img")).attr("id", "Imagedisplay");* as early as you need to store the img as a variable with out adding it to the document, then call *newImageBoxdiv.append(imageElement);* when you need to add it to the div.